# Calling behind method from iframe (another page) with ModalPopupExtender

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

I have ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender that have as popupcontrolid an iframe that loads another page.
I already manage to pass some parameters from the parent to the iframe page. Now I want passing back some information to the parent page when the user click a button.
My first solution was to write a javascript that reload the  parent pages with a get parameter, but in this way the WHOLE parent page is reload.

When closing the iframe page, I would like to call a "code behind" method on the parent page (passing some value), but this method must be called without a page reload (i.e. a button in a asp:UpdatePanel? But how to pass some value?).

Is there some way to do this?

Thanks in advance,
Alberto

Answer (score 0):

If you want some of the information on the parent page updated you'll need to write some JavaScript. Without seeing some of your existing code it will be hard to advise, but something to the effect of

```
window.top.parentFunctionNameToUpdateValues();
```

could trigger a post back to your parent based on an action in the iframe.

If nothing in the parent needs updating, simply have the form in the iframe post values to the parent, and then handle the onload in the parent to parse the values out that you need.